# Efficient way to convert 4 billion hex integers to decimal integer in R or python

Tags: python, r, data.table, large-data, categorical-data

I have a csv file with about 4.4 billion rows. It has 25 categorical columns, all of which are hexadecimal encoded integers, such as `EE6B2800` and `10642AC00`.

I have a machine with 3TB of RAM and used `data.table::fread` to load the dataset. R reads these values as strings (I'd be happy to use pandas instead).  I would like to convert these strings to integers.

One way to do this would be to decode the hex values to 64-bit integers, e.g.:

- "10642AC00" —> 4000000000
- "EE6B2800" —> 4400000000

One issue with this approach is that I can't quite do it with the raw strings. `bit64::as.integer64(c(0x10642AC00, 0xEE6B2800))` works, but I can't figure out how to convert the strings that I have.  Another issue is that 64 bit ints aren't supported by everything in R, and I'd really rather have 32 bit ints.

Another way to do this is to convert each unique value to sequential integers.  E.g.

- "10642AC00" —> 1
- "EE6B2800" —> 2

I can do this with `as.integer(factor(c("10642AC00", "EE6B2800")))`, which works but is very slow.  I've been running for a day and a half and its still chugging through the first column. I have no idea if this will every finish or if it will just blow up the RAM on my machine.

Is there a faster way to do something like `as.integer(factor(c("10642AC00", "EE6B2800")))`?  I'd be happy for an approximate output, e.g. sometimes there's a few gaps between integers or sometimes different hex values end up as the same integer.

My main requirement is that I want 32 bit ints, that mostly (but not necessarily perfectly) map 1-to-1 to the original hex strings.  Is there a faster and more efficient way to do something like this?  I'm fine with an operation that takes many hours per column, but would prefer not to have something that takes many days per column.

Is there a good library in R for fast, efficient integer hashing of string values?  Is there something clever I can do with the hex values?

Comment: The `djb2` algorithm might work well for string hashing in this instance. A fast implementation is available: `hrbrmiscpp::djb2_hash`.

Comment: I did a trial on 1M values and `match(x, x)` is about 25x faster than `as.integer(factor(x))`. `factor()` internally sorts the unique values in alphabetical order whereas `match(x, x)` will go in order of occurrence, so it might perform even better (relatively) on bigger data.

Comment: match doesn't need the second argument to be unique?

Comment: @Zach, no it doesn't, it will match the position of the _first_ of each repeated value in the second argument. Try `match(1:4, c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4))` for a demonstration.

Comment: awesome thank you

Comment: Look for fast factor function in dt repo. It uses forder to create factor

Answer (score 2):

My first reaction is: **why** ? What can you do with decimal values that you can't do with hex values?  See the package `gmp` , for example.

```
as.bigz('0xffee45454545')
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 281398829466949
```

FWIW, my package `bigBits` will happily convert arbitrarily large hex values to `bigz` integers (`gmp` package) and back again.

However, you may want to modify any existing `zip` algorithm, as that is specifically designed to map strings to (small) integers as part of the lossless compression.

Comment: The **why** is a very good point. This has a scent of XY problem.

Comment: This is a dumb question, but how do I convert the string "EE6B2800"?  do I need to paste the magic value "0x" in front of all my strings?

Comment: @zach  try it out and see!